# Adding voice support using Discord.Net v1.0.0

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm currently working on a Discord bot using Discord.Net.
I want to add voice support, but the documentation I found is for version 0.9.4 and not the latest one. Also the respective NuGet-Package says it is deprecated.

Is there another (new?) way adding voice support (the old one maybe doesn't work in future versions) or can I just use the one described in the outdated version?

Thx for your help!

Comment: I'm still using the deprecated `Discord.Net.Audio` for now. The Discord.Net devs are working on a rewrite for the audio module documentation. It's using Rest and FFMPEG, you can see its documentation (when rewritten) at https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/voice/sending-voice.html and samples at https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/tree/af7943e62a97fa3d17fd2d0eb8d2e98603b8ff81/docs/guides/voice/samples